# How to get column names as the order in table

Tags: mysql

I have this table

```
 CREATE TABLE prodotti(
 type_prod varchar(10) not null,
 model_prod varchar(10) not null,
 brand_prod varchar(20) not null,
 name_prod varchar(30) not null,
 year_prod int not null,
 description_prod varchar(500) not null,
 price_prod float not null,
 qnt_prod int not null,
 PRIMARY KEY(type_prod,model_prod) );
```

To get the column names I used this query:

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'prodotti'
```

but the query returns `COLUMN_NAMES` in alphabetical order.

Is there a way to get this names in the same order as `CREATE TABLE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a column that has ordinal position.

```
SELECT
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'prodotti'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: @Wuagliono No problem and please mark as answer if so.